Does the Unbreaking Enchantment affect how much exp is needed to fully repair equipment with the mending enchantment?
I'm working on end-game mining gear. I want to ensure that I don't lose my pickaxe that took a significant amount of time to upgrade/enchant but I don't want it to be a huge amount of work to keep in good repair either.
From the players perspective it appears that Unbreaking increases the "durability points" of my tools, so like, if I have 100 durability with no enchantment, unbreaking 1 might give a tool 200 durability, unbreaking 2 would be 300 durability and so on.
That said, I don't know if that's actually how it works. If it is I'm wondering if I would need extra experience orbs to repair a tool with unbreaking 3, meaning repairing it would take more effort to get the requisite experience. Is this the case or am I misunderstanding the mechanics here?

Nope. Unbreaking reduces the chance of a use of a tool costing its durability.
It does NOT increase durability (points), and therefore does not affect mending and the amount of XP to repair.
You can research the these mechanics at the Minecraft Wiki, like the unbreaking page or the mending page.
